# Access Control questions

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I have a couple of questions on access control and Group Policy

We use a term server for employee's to get certain documents, access databases, etc.

I'm trying to build a new access control plan because we have a lot of employees who like to snoop and see how much other people are making. I've tried to lock down users but I'm having a hard time on a few issues.

I want only certain people to be able to roam freely. (ME and the two Owners) and then I need HR department to be able to access folders,databses,etc.

We have two hard drives on this server. (C: and D:)

C: holds the OS and a few programs and D: holds database files, forums, profiles, payroll info,etc. The way I have users locked down now is that they cant go to my computer, explorer,etc. But I did make shortcuts to a scanning folder and to a Tree folder (misc documents). if the users is very snoopy he can still browse through the C: and D: drive.

Users clicks on shortcut and on the right under OTHER PLACES. It lists the drives. I can for the life of me find the permission in group policy's to turn this off. So this is my first questions. What are some of the GP permission I want to find to secure my server from unwanted pokers?

My next question.

Are HR department also does are payroll. On are D: drive I have two folders HR and Payroll. How can I make it that only certain people can read,edit that info. When I make a separate group and I can never get it works. It seems I have to click deny on all users but then no one can access the info..

Thanks.

Comment: First rule of 'Deny' rules: they take precedent over everything. Useful if an HR person is having an HR action performed against them, and you need to keep them out of the folder holding the documents related to that. A folder that they would otherwise have perfectly legitimate access to.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 - That's technically not correct. An explicit Allow takes precedence over an inherited Deny. Only an explicit Deny takes precedence over any other NTFS permission.

Comment: so whats the best method? Get rife of all users and just add groups? Can I do this for software folders?

Comment: 1. Trying to restrict access to certain file locations by hiding those locations isn't a solution. 2. Use Security groups and NTFS permissions to restrict access to sensitive data to just those users who need access to that data. 3. This is a fairly basic undertaking and if you're struggling with it you may want to enlist the assistance of a consultant.

Answer (score 1):

You should study [the article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770962.aspx) about NTFS permissions i think. By default these permissions follow principal of "implicit deny". That's mean users who have not explicitly assigned permissions by defaut get access denial. So you should remove from folders you want to deny access NTFS permissions to groups like "authenticated users" and leave only those permissions, which grant access to only appropriate groups (for example "HR" group)

Comment: so remove all users and setup a bunch of groups?

Comment: @user160605 Group-based permission structures are a lot more maintainable in the long run, so yes.